# py.test: ImportError - cannot import ----

Tags: python, virtualenv, importerror

I am using someone else's code, available on GitHub. To run their code I created a `virtualenv` and installed all the dependencies listed - both python libraries and clones of other repositories. When I proceed to run the included tests, I get an `ImportError`:

```
    Namespace(all=False, regr=False, sci=False, unit=True)
    [localhost] local: py.test -x -v engine/test
    ==================================================================================== test session starts =====================================================================================
    platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.6, pytest-2.8.2, py-1.4.31, pluggy-0.3.1 -- /home/compomics/local/METASPACE/SM_distributed/SM_engine/bin/python
    cachedir: engine/test/.cache
    rootdir: /home/compomics/local/METASPACE/SM_distributed/engine/test, inifile: 
    collecting 6 items / 1 errors
    =========================================================================================== ERRORS ===========================================================================================
    _______________________________________________________________________ ERROR collecting test_formula_img_validator.py _______________________________________________________________________
    engine/test/test_formula_img_validator.py:7: in <module>
        from engine.formula_img_validator import filter_sf_images,get_compute_img_measures, ImgMeasures
    engine/formula_img_validator.py:7: in <module>
        from pyIMS.image_measures import measure_of_chaos, isotope_image_correlation, isotope_pattern_match
    E   ImportError: cannot import name measure_of_chaos
    !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: stopping after 1 failures !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    ================================================================================== 1 error in 0.99 seconds ===================================================================================

    Fatal error: local() encountered an error (return code 2) while executing 'py.test -x -v engine/test'
```

However, if I open the python interpreter and try to do the exact same imports, it does it just fine without any error. Similar questions suggested:

- adding an empty `__init__.py` to the test directory
- making sure `pytest` is installed in the virtualenv

I did both these things, and the error persists.

I added to the beginning of the test script:

```
    import os
    print(os.environ["PYTHONPATH"].split(os.pathsep))
    print(os.listdir("."))
```

and confirmed that the folder from where I'm trying to import is indeed in the resulting list.

Not sure how to proceed. Would appreciate any help I can get :)

Comment: conflict in libraries

Answer (score 0):

there was a conflict with other library

EDIT - this was my own stupidity for not remembering I had cloned a previous version of the dependent repos, which was also on my path, and that did not include the function this code was trying to load. Sorry for not having deleted the question when I noticed, I couldn't for the life of me find the delete button :)

Comment: Please try to phrase the answer so that it may help others who have the same problem. In particular, be specific what other library caused the conflict and how you resolved it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11389833)

Comment: @Prune Be watchful, this *is* the answer from the OP.  Not a great one, but still is an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In file formula_img_validator.py change

```
from pyIMS.image_measures import measure_of_chaos,isotope_image_correlation, isotope_pattern_match
```

to

```
from engine.pyIMS.image_measures import measure_of_chaos, isotope_image_correlation, isotope_pattern_match
```

That'll solve the problem. For complete solution [go to GitHub for new updated code](https://github.com/SpatialMetabolomics/SM_distributed/commit/07bcfd2ef6aa8414d8a702a5d4807430db3045d6).